# Is there a way to to bind Python methods to a Tkinter widget through a SEPARATE class?

Tags: python, tkinter

Is there a way to to bind Python methods to a Tkinter widget through a SEPARATE class ? (ie. the methods are in a DIFFERENT class from the tkinter widget) ?

SPECIFICALLY the Checkbutton() widget ?

Example:

```
def __init__(self, master):

    self.var = IntVar()    
    c = Checkbutton(master, text="Enable a tab", variable=self.var, command=self.cb)
    c.pack()
    

def cb(self, event)

    print("Variable is", self.var.get())
```

... for the second method "cb" -- is it possible to write it inside a different class from the one holding the def **init**(self, master) constructor ?

EDIT: passing the variable self.var into the cb method by doing this:

`command=self.cb(self.var)`

makes the program work IMPROPERLY apparently.

EDIT: Question has been answered ! Thank you very much !

Comment: Yes, via instance of another class.  But if you want to access instance variables of this class, you need to pass `self` to the callback of another class.

Comment: acw1668 - Could you show me through a code example ? I think I addressed this under my EDITS note above. When I instantiate an object and try to pass the instance variables of this class into the object via the binded tkinter methods, the program doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you ca. The problem with `command=self.cb(self.var)` is that you can't pass arguments to the method in command, only the method itself, but you can work around this using lambda function, like in `command=lambda: self.cb(self.var)`. Here is a small reproducible example:

```
import tkinter as tk 

class Printer(object):
    def print_text(self, text):
        print(text)

class Button(tk.Button):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        other = Printer()
        super(Button, self).__init__(parent, text='press', command=lambda: other.print_text('test'))

root = tk.Tk()
Button(root).pack()
root.mainloop()
```